# Why does translateHttpLoader call the json translation file so many times?

Tags: ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I am using ngx translate with @ionic/angular 5.9.4, Here is my implementation for it in app.module:

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
 TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: "en",
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    })

})
```

The issue is that when I log into the app, the network in the browser shows a huge number of calls to en.json, more than 100 in total, as shown below:

> Request URL: http://localhost:8100/assets/i18n/en.json
> Request Method:
> GET Status Code: 304 Not Modified

and

> Request URL: http://localhost:8100/assets/i18n/en.json Request Method:
> GET Status Code: 200 OK

Comment: there is an open issue over here https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader/issues/68. One of the solutions is to do a simple caching.